# Getting error No module named 'azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice' while executing on server

Tags: python, azure

I have a script that runs perfectly fine on my local machine using Anaconda
`from azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice import BlockBlobService`
I installed it via:  `pip install azure-storage-blob`.

I migrated the script to a server and first did `pip install azure-storage-blob`. This ran without any issues. Now when I execute `from azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice import BlockBlobService`, I get the error **No module named 'azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice'**.

I went into the site-packages folder on the server and could not find the file "blockblobservice.py" under **azure/storge/blob** folder. Below are the list of files and folders I see under this folder on the server:

```
__init__.py
_blob_service_client.py
_blob_client.py
_deserialize.py
_container_client.py
_lease.py
_download.py
_shared_access_signature.py
_serialize.py
_models.py
_version.py
_upload_helpers.py
_generated
aio
_shared
__pycache__
```

pip freeze | grep azure returns below information:

```
azure-common==1.1.25
azure-core==1.6.0
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-storage-blob==12.3.2
azure-storage-nspkg==3.1.0
```

Thanks in advance, for your help in resolving this!

Answer (score 0):

`azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice` is part of older Azure Storage SDK (`azure-storage`) and not the newer one (`azure-storage-blob`).

I believe the reason why code is working on your machine is because you have the older SDK still present on your machine. You can confirm this by going into `site-packages/azure/storage/blob` folder on your local machine. You should see `blockblobservice.py` file there.

Comment: I executed the newer SDK by ```pip install azure-storage-blob``` still I see the same error. Which package am I missing here?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you're not missing anything. `azure-storage-blob` is completely different than the old SDK (which I believe you can't download anymore). For example, there's a separate class called `BlobClient` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python) to deal with Blobs.