# from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

When I try to import BaseBlobService on my IDE (Pycharm), it throw an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice'

However it works fine on Databricks

Answer (score 0):

Please **note** that, **`azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice`** belongs to **`azure-storage`** the older version of Azure Storage SDK. The newer one is **`azure-storage-blob`**.

Check whether you are using the older SDK going to this **`site-packages/azure/storage/blob`** in your machine and check the **`blockblobservice.py`** file.

You can install the **latest version of Azure Storage SDK** by executing the below command:

```py
pip install azure-storage-blob
```

And use [**BlobServiceClient**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python) instead of BaseBlobService.

***If still the issue persists, try upgrading the SDK like below:***

```py
pip install azure-storage-blob --upgrade
```

And also check whether **`azure-storage`** package is installed using **`pip list`**, If present the uninstall it.

**References:**

[Getting error No module named 'azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice' while executing on server by Gaurav Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600385/getting-error-no-module-named-azure-storage-blob-blockblobservice-while-execut)

[error importing 'BlobServiceClient' from 'azure.storage.blob' by rakshith91](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58768443/error-importing-blobserviceclient-from-azure-storage-blob)